Do continued fractions always converge?
Say I have a continued fraction in this form:
$$a_0 + \dfrac{b_0}{a_1 + \dfrac{b_1}{a_2 + \dfrac{b_2}{\cdots}}}$$
Does it always converge? If not, how can I know if it does? An example that comes to my mind is a fraction in the form:
$$x = a + \dfrac{b}{a + \dfrac{b}{a + \dfrac b{\cdots}}}$$
That is:
$$x = a+\frac bx\implies x^2 - ax - b = 0$$
Now if we choose $a,b$ such that $a^2 + 4b < 0$, the equation will have two solutions in $\mathbb C\smallsetminus\mathbb R$. Does this mean that the fraction converges to a complex number? Or that it does not converge?

That's a great example. What have you tried? Hint: can you write down a recursive formula for the sequence of fractions truncated after $n$ divisions?

Your Criteria will make $b$ negative & you will get alternating terms in the "convergents" hence it will not converge.

@ChrisLewis like $a_0=a$, $a_{n+1} = a + \dfrac b{a_n}$?

@Elvis yup. That lets you work a bit more formally with the fraction. So now you can show that, if the sequence $a_n$ converges, it must converge to a complex number with non-zero imaginary part (under the condition you gave). But what can you say about every term of the sequence?

By the way, the condition you gave is correct. You can have $b<0$ and still get a convergent sequence (eg $(a,b)=(3,-1)$)

@ChrisLewis every term of the sequence is real, so the sequence does not converge?

@Elvis exactly! Of course, continued fractions are usually restricted to only be made up of positive integers. What can you say about convergence under that condition?

@ChrisLewis not sure if they always converge, but I'd say yes. Oh, and I had another question: the only way to make a continued fraction converge to a complex number is to use complex numbers in it, right?

@Elvis you can use the sequence idea to prove convergence for positive integer entries. It might be interesting to explore what happens in the complex plane, but you'd have some options for defining the fraction/sequence. (It'll be tricky because you're getting quite far from the idea of continued fractions there)

@ChrisLewis I asked the question because of something that didn't convince me in an answer. Here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097697/a-complex-number-abi-as-a-continued-fraction/
Both of the answers say that you can obtain a complex number by only using integers in a continued fraction.
EDIT: I just noticed there's a new answer saying you can't, makes more sense to me.

Euler provided a beautiful formula that links between the infinite continued fraction and the infinite series
$$a_0 + a_0a_1 + a_0a_1a_2+... + a_0a_1...a_n =  \dfrac{a_0}{1 - \dfrac{a_1}{1 + a_1 - \dfrac{a_2}{1+a_2-\dfrac{\cdots}{\cdots\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{1+a_{n-1}-\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}}}}}}$$
Or more compactly
$$a_0 + a_0a_1 + a_0a_1a_2+... + a_0a_1...a_n = \frac{a_0}{1-}\frac{a_1}{1+a_1-}\frac{a_2}{1+a_2-}\cdots\frac{a_{n-1}}{1+a_{n-1}-}\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$$
Or even more compactly using Gauss notation:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \prod_{i = 0}^k a_k = \frac{a_0}{1+}\mathop{\vcenter{\huge \mathrm K}}_{k=1}^n\,\frac{-a_k}{1+a_k}$$
To generalize this result one can use equivalence transformation
$$\frac{a_0}{b_0+}\frac{a_1}{b_1+}\frac{a_2}{b_2+}\cdots = \frac{c_0a_0}{c_0b_0+}\frac{c_0c_1a_1}{c_1b_1+}\frac{c_1c_2a_2}{c_2b_2+}\cdots$$
In short, you can derive the sum version of a continued fraction, then show whether the continued fraction converges or not via the sum.

Honestly I've never seen that big K notation in my life, but it looks so interesting. How does it work?

@Elvis $\displaystyle{\mathop{\vcenter{\large \mathrm K}}{k=1}^1,\dfrac{a_k}{b_k} = \dfrac{a_1}{b_1}}$, $\displaystyle{\mathop{\vcenter{\large \mathrm K}}{k=1}^2,\dfrac{a_k}{b_k} = \dfrac{a_1}{b_1 + \dfrac{a_2}{b_2}}}$ and so on
